# browser downloads rails response as a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, devise

I have been fiddling with rails apps for a while and I sometimes see this behavior on Safari (could be on other browsers as well, not sure) where the browser downloads the response as a file instead of rendering it in the browser. I wonder why that is.

The last time it happened made me decide to ask on stack overflow. My current setup is a very basic rails app that implements devise and I get a file named 'sign_in.admin' with just the following content:

`You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

I know that string comes from the devise locale and is supposed to be rendered with a layout, but the browser just downloads it as a file as if I chose to 'Download linked file as...' It's happened to me before where instead of rails routing me somewhere it downloads a file.  Can somebody explain why my browser sometimes does that?  I have all the latest updates.

Comment: What url you see in the browser when the file is being downloaded? Can you check Safari Web Inspector for server response?

Comment: I probably could next time it happens, but it seemed common enough that a general response could answer the problem, i.e. when does the browser just download a file?  I mean, I don't even know how I would accomplish that behavior even if I were actually trying.

Comment: So for the same action in the same browser you are getting this behaviour randomly, is that correct?

Comment: i'm sure there is a pattern to the frequency, that's what i'm trying to figure out of course, but let's just say that i know very little about that, otherwise it is definitely tied to certain controller actions, and i'm pretty sure it's happened both in firefox and safari, all preferences default.

Comment: I'm sure it's because of the app then — is there any specific behavior in the controllers that have restricted access, other that simple CRUD?

Comment: you're saying that random file downloads is caused by controllers actions access restrictions in my app?  that doesn't make much sense and i haven't even done anything like that, even so, like i said, I wouldn't even know how to accomplish that behavior even if I were actually trying to.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is caused by those controllers, I'm just asking about them because the error message in downloaded file was about restricted access — that's why I think it's a good place to start looking at the app. Just trying to help and point you to the right direction

Comment: I know you are. I'm just communicating what I think is or isn't the cause. please don't mind that. I've also seen this behavior where it downloads an empty file, that leads me to think what you're saying doesn't explain it all.

Comment: Could be true. What webserver do you use to serve those Rails apps?

Comment: i use apache 2 with phusion on a macbook air